# Postgres constraints: EXCLUDE (name WITH =) vs partial unique index

Tags: postgresql, constraint, unique-constraint, exclusion-constraint

I am refactoring my database constraint for such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  name text NOT NULL,
  status text NOT NULL
);
```

A former engineer working on the project had such a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE products
  ADD CONSTRAINT unique_active_name
  EXCLUDE (name WITH =)
  WHERE (status = 'active' AND name <> '');
```

I am wondering if it is equivalent to such a partial unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_active_name
  ON products(name)
  WHERE (status = 'active' AND name <> '');
```

I did not quite get the documentation for `EXCLUDE`, and would like to improve things. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, both approaches are basically identically.